# AWS:What will be more price efficient Instance or Reserved Instance for EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a regular AWS EC2 m3.large instance that I use for a few days a month, when I'm not using it I stop it, and just start it when I need it. I have the understanding that I only pay for it when it is actually running, is that correct ?

I've just recently noticed *reserved instances*, I'm happy to commit to a term of a few years, however I don't need to use it every day. So assuming my first assumption is correct does that also apply to reserved instances or do i have to pay every day whether or not Im using.

If is a good idea can I convert my existing instance to a reserved instance or do I have to setup a new machine from scratch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pay for reserved instance even if you are not using it. The capacity is already reserved for it and you may have already paid a partial payment upfront for you or you can choose no upfront. Reserved instance is **use it or lose it**.

You can use a calculator and see if reserved instance can save you $$.

You can convert your on-demand to reserved instance just by **reserving an instance of same type in the same availability zone**. AWS has made the instance reservation more flexible recently but if you are running a single instance, just reserve an instance of same type in the same availability zone. You can choose partial/no upfront, one or three year terms.

In `us-east-1`, on-demand cost for `m4.large` is $0.10/hour.

- Monthly on-demand cost is: **$72/month**
- Approximate reserved instance (one year) cost with no upfront: **$50/month**
- Number of on-demand hours for $50: **500 hours** (20 days)

If you plan to run for less than 500 hours/month, then you should go for on-demand. Remember, with **reserved instances you are guaranteed an instance by AWS**. Sometimes, on-demand may run out of capacity and you have to choose a different instance type. It is very rare but happens sometimes.

Comment: Hi, I realize that, but not sure what that exactly means could you address my specific questions please.

Comment: So to be clear if you reserve it you are paying 24 hours  day from that moment whether its running or not?

Comment: @PaulTaylor yes. Minimum commitment is one year.

Comment: Right okay best to stick to spot for now then, but perhaps I could a couple of other questions that have come out of this, Im using m3 in Uk/Ireland because based in uk but would us be cheaper, should I move fro m3 to m4 - they seem to be cheaper and better

Comment: yes. m4 is current gen and better. And `spot` is different from `on-demand`.

Answer (score 1):

If you "reserve" an instance you have to pay for it.
m3.large instances that you stop you do not have to pay for, but keep in mind you might have to pay for other things like the EBS volume attached.

Judging by what you've said, its sounds like it's cheaper to start/stop the instance when you need it.

Comment: so im correct to say Idon't have to pay for my instance if I stop it, but I would have no such saving using a reserved instance ?

Comment: I do have an additional ebs volume that I have to pay for continually, but this is only a small cost.

Comment: yep.  stopping it = saves you money.  running it as a reserved = you are paying for it no matter what, amazon is essentially reserving spot for your instance so you get it at a cheaper rate however if it runs or not its not their problem you're still being billed.